# JavaFX: изменить текст label с потока

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, label

знаю что очень много похожих тем и, побродив по просторам интернета, наткнулся на возможные решения моей проблемы с помощью Task, Service и метода Platform.runLater(). Увы, не могу подстроить эти варианты под свой код в котором есть Контроллер пользовательского интерфейса и Мой класс - поток.
Итак вопрос:

Что посоветуете да изменения метки curMoney из потока в классе Tactic?

```
public class Tactic  implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        money += income;
        System.out.println((int)money); // Вместо этого ожидается label.setText(money);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(speed);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Контроллер

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller {

@FXML
private Label curMoney;

@FXML
private Label curIncome;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Tactic());
    thread.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь классом `Task` из `JavaFX`. Этот класс служит для создания потоков и может обновлять нужные Вам `Label` и не только при помощи своих методов.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не понимаю как его использовать, а именно: Что ставить вместо Void____ Task task = new Task<Void>()____И что возвращать: ____
        return null;

Comment: Если Вам нужно что бы поток что-то вернул,то там где `Void` ставьте класс, объект которого поток должен Вам вернуть и в `return` метода `call` пишете логику и возвращаете. Если ничего не надо возвращать то оставляете `Void` и `return null` - это значит что поток просто отработает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Tactic  implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            money += income;

            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                // Тут выводим результат в интерфейс
                label.setText(money);
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(speed);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Только позаботьтесь о синхронизации переменной `money`

Comment: Вылазит Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Меня смущает присваивание текста при помощи такого способа:

Platform.runLater(() -> new Controller().setCurMoney(String.valueOf(money))). Правильно?

Comment: @Митяй Не знаю ваших целей, но скорее всего - нет, не правильно. Передайте в `Tactic` объект `Controller` и уже через него устанавливайте текст в `Platform.runLater`.